# Replace words in a tweet with numeric value of their frequency

Tags: r

I am facing a problem to replace words in a tweet with the numeric value of their frequency.

I have already made a data frame showing the words ranked by their frequency.

Now I want to substitute the words in the tweets with the frequency rank of every word.

I attached snips of my data frames.

Tweets and word frequency data:

[image: img]

My goal is that a tweets looks like this:

```
[1] [3] [7] [11] [18] [12] [10] [5] [3] [44] [23] [46] [2] [90]
```

The `[1]` means that it is the most frequent word in the dataset.

Any help appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think `stringr::str_replace_all` is an efficient way to go about it: just pass it a named vector with your word frequency and you're done.

See reprex below. The first few lines just generate random data; your frequency table looks like the `df` I generated below.

```r
sentence <- "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

sentence_split <- unique(as.character(stringr::str_split(string = sentence, pattern = " ", simplify = TRUE)))

names(sentence_split) <- sample(x = 1:1000, size = length(sentence_split))

df <- data.frame(word = sentence_split,
                 n = sample(x = 1:1000, size = length(sentence_split)))

df
#>    word   n
#>    the    740
#>    quick  192
#>    brown  145
#>    fox    809
#>    jumps  700
#>    over   910
#>    lazy   352
#>    dog    256

replace_vector <- paste0("[", df$n, "]")
names(replace_vector) <- df$word

stringr::str_replace_all(string = sentence, pattern = replace_vector)
#> [1] "[740] [192] [145] [809] [700] [910] [740] [352] [256]"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Hey, sorry for my belated reply and thanks a lot for your help. I tried your suggestion and now I´m facing two small issues.
1. I´m only able to replace the words of one column, not the entire data frame
2. I´m only able to see the replacement of the word with their frequency values as an output and I´m not able to replace them "permanently" in the data frame.
Do you have any idea where I´m doing something wrong?
Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance

Comment: If you have a data frame with text columns,  and want to assign it back, after creating `replace_vector` you could do something like: `df$replaced <- stringr::str_replace_all(string = df$column_with_text, pattern = replace_vector)`. You can repeat for more columns, or if they are many, something like `purrr::purrr::map_dfc(df_with_text_columns, function(x) (stringr::str_replace_all(x, pattern = replace_vector))`.